# What does "ってっか" mean?

Tags: grammar

For full context:

> お父ちゃんも朝ごはん食ってっかね

My attempt at translation:

> Dad's having breakfast right now, too.

I'm having some trouble with "ってっか"? "って" is "という", right? But "っ" after "て", I don't really understand.

Comment: could be a shortened version of 食っていかない...?

Comment: ^ that would be 食ってかね(え).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sentence is a contracted version of お父{とう}ちゃんも朝｛あさ｝ごはん食｛く｝ってるかね, 'Is Dad (not necessarily the speaker's father in this case) having breakfast too?'

る into っ or ん (depending on the next sound) is a very common sound change in casual speech.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I get the impression the speaker is お父ちゃん's father, speaking to one of his (the speaker's) grandchildren.